# how to fix linking pages with on another in same website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

I've created a default mvc web application in visual studio 2017. the issue i'm facing is when i run this application it shows me the main interface and after it when i click the contact us page in header it shows nothing. kindly help me how to put link interconnection between them. i've already tried @actionlink

```
<!-- The navigation menu -->
<div class="navbar">
    <a class="active" href="@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Clothing</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">Track Order</a>
```

Comment: issue resolved thankyou

Comment: Delete the question or explain.

Answer (score 1):

`@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")` creates an anchor tag `<a href="/Home/Index">Home</a>`,

`@Url.Action("Home", "Index")` creates a url `/Home`

so you can use this:

```
<!-- The navigation menu -->
<div class="navbar">
    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
    <a href="#">Clothing</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">Track Order</a>
```

or this:

```
<!-- The navigation menu -->
<div class="navbar">
    <a class="active" href="@Url.Action("Home", "Index")">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Clothing</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">Track Order</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for provide an action link on click event

```
<div class="navbar">
<a class="active" href="@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")">Home</a>
<a href="#">Clothing</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")" >Contact</a>
<a href="#">Track Order</a>
```